# React form hook setValue overwrites placeholder value

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-hook-form

I have an edit user form. When I get data from API, I am able to setValue of the form field Array. But when I setValue of a `formField` ie first name or last name, it overwrites the placeholder value. But in the case `useFieldArray` it works fine. Please find the form updating code as below -

```
const handleGetUser = (user: UsersDataSourceModel) => {
    if (!_.isEmpty(user)) {
        setValue('firstName', user.firstName, {shouldTouch: true});
        setValue('lastName', user.lastName, {shouldTouch: true});
        setValue('emailId', user.emailId, {shouldTouch: true});
        if (user.roles.length) {
            user.roles.map((role, index) => {
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.region`, role.region);
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleId`, role.roleId);
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.countryId`, role.countryId);
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.neverExpireRole`, role.neverExpireRole);
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.roleExpiryDate`, role.roleExpiryDate);
                setValue(`userCountryRoleMappings.${index}.isReadOnly`, role.isReadOnly);
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Pleae refer the image attached. It is how looking when edit form page is visited.[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a ton!

Comment: It would be great if you can show more about the `setValue` and the form codes.

Comment: @brandonwie setValue is the method provided by react hook form.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the one more clue.

I found a similar issue that was reported on `react-hook-form` about `setValue` and `placeholder` view simultaneously.

https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/1556

From the link above, check out `@devrnt`'s comment. You may find it helpful.

I copied his comment below just for the sake of your time.

---

[@devrnt](https://github.com/devrnt)'s comment

Sandbox 1
Seems like a related issue: [mui/material-ui#718](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/718)
I would suggest to watch on the 'TextFieldTwo' value and manually set the shrink option.
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-mountain-9532t

Sandbox 2
Can be fixed by setting the mode in useForm to onChange. Do mind that this often comes with a significant impact on performances.
https://codesandbox.io/s/setremoteinputcontroller-wwsdt

Answer (score 0):

So when you use material, yup and react-hook-form there are some problems. While looking at material ui and its component, I came across this below prop -

```
InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
```

So if you have any textField, you should use it like -

```
<TextField 
   InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} 
   size="small" 
   fullWidth 
   {...register('lastName')} 
   required
   label="Last Name" 
   variant="outlined" 
/>
```