Value rendered over Placeholder in material-design-ui-kit (React) + react-hook-form
TLDR: Problem:
In MDBInput, a value renders over placeholder causing not readable any of them.
Motivation:
Moreless a newbie, trying to learn on-the-fly. I am tying to implement modal popup with form used to edit the selected item in the window. Selected value is on button click passed to the editor-component, which should show a form to edit the value. So, the point here is that the opened form has preset current value in the input.
Current implementation
A component gets the item to edit via props. As this value changes dynamicaly, I use useEffects() to adjust the value when necessary via react-form-hook build-in function setValue.
The value gets correctly propagated into the input; however, as the input has also the placeholder with the value, both value and placeholder text are rendered in the text input.
If the text/value is changed, the placeholder appears correctly in the top-left "header" of the inputbox.
What I have tried
Directly setting value causes that the value cannot be later changed. Using defaultValues on init or reset() funtion have the same invalid behavior.
I have also found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75180816/react-form-hook-setvalue-overwrites-placeholder-value, but have no idea how to adapt this to my solution.
What I am looking for?

a) Probably I am using those technologies together somehow incorrectly and I am missing some important part. In this case, a help/code correction will be appreciated.
b) Probably I did not choose correct technologies. In this case, a suggetions to migrate solution to different technologies are also appreciated.

Codes
Source codes are available at sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/form-input-not-working-shk3jx
In short:
import {
  MDBBtn,
  MDBCol,
  MDBContainer,
  MDBInput,
  MDBRow,
} from "mdb-react-ui-kit";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "mdb-react-ui-kit/dist/css/mdb.min.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";

interface Props {
  title: string;
}

interface IFormInput {
  title: string;
}

export function MyForm(props: Props) {
  const {
    register,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>({
    mode: "onChange",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue("title", props.title);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <MDBContainer>
        <MDBRow>
          <MDBCol sm={4}>
            <form>
              <MDBInput
                {...register("title")}
                className="mb-4"
                type="title"
                id="title"
                label="Folder title"
              />
            </form>
          </MDBCol>
        </MDBRow>
      </MDBContainer>
    </div>
  );
}


